# Golang Mysql connectex socket block

Tags: mysql, sockets, go

I use the "go-sql-driver/mysql" driver.
I have a product table that has a few dependencies. So i Select the product and get dependencies that would create cartesian products in subqueries. Usually there is a 200 products limit to have a better performance but in rare cases the limit will be removed or raised to lets say 3000-5000 then then i will get the following error:

> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: Normalerweise darf jede
>   Socketadresse (Protokoll, Netzwerkadresse oder Anschluss) nur jeweils
>   einmal verwendet werden.

which basically means:

> connectex: Use every Socketaddress only once.

This is a snipped from my code, basically all my query-functions are build like that:

```
mysql := this.DBController.Connect()
defer mysql.Close()
.
.
.
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&x, &y, &z)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("DBFetchMachines: Scan Error")
        log.Println(err)
    }
    product.PurchasePrice = this.priceR.DBFetchPurchasePriceByProductID(product.ID)
    product.SellingPrice = this.priceR.DBFetchSellingPriceByProductID(product.ID)
    product.DealerContact = this.contactR.DBGetBasicContact(product.DealerContact.ID)
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When i just query 200-1000 rows there is no issue.
Is this maybe a OS related issue? I use Win10 64Bit as my dev machine.

Comment: Sounds like a windows ulimit thing to me.. I don't use windows so that more of a guess.. read here https://support.socketlabs.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/61/0/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted

Secondly if you are running out of sockets, then you have too many connections open and aren't closing them properly when your done with them.. Just looking at the code alone you are spawning 3 connections per loop.. not to mention any others above that...

Comment: See here as well http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access you can cherry pick from this article for best practices with your sql connections

Comment: @reticentroot the mysql-lib has a connection managment. When i understand the DOC correct I am suppose to set a MaxOpenConns and the Open/Close just "Block" and "Release" the conns for use. I will check  your first Commend and i will try to play a bit with this values but i never saw the conn status in the mysql dashboard spike. its always around 3-6 during the queries.

Comment: @reticentroot Okay i found the issue. I had created a new DBHandler with every "Connect()". So my limitation where kinda useless. I put everything now in a global handler and now the limitation works. Thanks for bringing me on the right tracks

Comment: @reticentroot can you post the "best practise" comment as answer so i can mark it?

Comment: you can go ahead and post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **reticentroot** in the comments suggested i checked  [alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access) for some best practices examples. I choose **Dependency injection** and it works like a charm.